# PHP Using a Ternary Result inside the result

Tags: php, conditional-statements, ternary

I need use a ternary conditional result inside my called function. Is this possible?

```
(new SaveData($query))->idSaved() ? letsgo('gotrue', idSaved()) : letsgo('gofalse');
```

It's possible use result of my ternary inside that?
In this case, idSaved() return the Inserted ID on my database.

Actually I use:

```
$res = new SaveData($query);
$res->idSaved() ? letsgo('gotrue', $res->idSaved()) : letsgo('gofalse');
```

Comment: Don't you mean `$res ? letsgo('gotrue', $res) : letsgo('gofalse');`?

Comment: The more ternaries you add the less readable, and therefore maintainable, the code gets. Barmar's solution certainly works, but it is yet more confusing to read. I would honestly suggest doing away with the ternary altogether and fleshing it out to and `if(){}else{}` block.

Comment: On a side note, I'd recommend refactoring (or writing a wrapper for) `idSaved()` so you pass it only one value, and it determines whether to use 'gotrue' or 'gofalse' based on whether the value received is true or false. This will simplify your calls to `idSaved()` and eliminate the need for [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) in every call.

Comment: @Barmar yes. Edited!

Comment: I corrected the second line, I had copied it wrong

Comment: @Sammitch then you think is more readable/recommended:  `if ($res = new SaveData($query)) { letsgo('gotrue', $res->idSaved()); } else { letsgo('gofalse'); }` . Nice suggestion. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the variable inside the ternary:

```
($res = (new SaveData($query))->idSaved()) ? letsgo('gotrue', $res) : letsgo('gofalse')
```

Comment: I never tried this way before. I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I agree with Sammitch's comment above. This is confusing.